# The quotient of the product of all positive odd numbers and the product of all natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

On a quiz I saw the equation:
$$a_{n}=\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{n!}$$
and I was asked to use a graph of it in order to guess if it does converges or diverges as $n \to \infty$, and if it converge to "guess" $\lim_{ n \to \infty } a_{n}$.

The graph did diverge and I put that down as the answer, but the wording was interesting to me, so I tried to find the limit to see if it did. I came up with
$$\lim_{ n \to \infty } a_{n} =\lim_{ n \to \infty }\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot n}= \lim_{ n \to \infty }\frac{1}{2\cdot4\cdot6\dots n}$$
The numerator is every odd number multiplied together, and the denominator is every natural number multiplied together, so if they cancel out, it should just be 1/(product of every even natural number)

Giving this to Wolfram Alpha gave me
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\prod_{x=1}^{n}(2x-1)}{n!}=\infty$$
I'm aware that rearranging the addends in infinite sums can change it, is that also true for infinite products? Is what I did correct or is there something I'm missing

Comment: your cancellation is wrong. The numerator is _not_ every odd number multiplied together, it's the first $n$ odd numbers. Not all of them are a part of the first $n$ natural numbers. Now you can take the limit (blow up $n$) and you'll see it diverges.

Comment: Only odd numbers up to $n$ cancel out, not all of them.

Comment: This is true for any finite value of n, however when n is infinity, the top IS every odd number, and the bottom IS every natural number

Comment: $n$ is **not** infinity. $n$ is always a natural number and infinity is not a natural number. The notation does not indicate that $\infty$ is to be substituted for $n$, only that $n$ takes on increasingly larger values, without end. An infinite product is the limit of partial products (if it exists). In other words, it's not as simple as applying your intuition regarding infinity. After all, if $n$ truly _was_ infinity, the numerator and denominator would also contain every single positive real number, and then you'd be dealing with a whole different kind of beast!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a better idea of how fast $a_n$ grows, I'd do the following. First, note that
\begin{aligned}
a_n &= \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdots n} \\
&= \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdots n} \cdot
\frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n-2)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n-2)} \\
&= \frac{(2n-1)!}{n!} \cdot \frac{1}{(2\cdot 1) \cdot (2\cdot 2) \cdot (2\cdot 3) \cdots (2(n-1))} \\
&= \frac{(2n-1)!}{n!} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{n-1}(1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (n-1))} \\
&= \frac{(2n-1)!}{2^{n-1}n!(n-1)!}.
\end{aligned}

Now, we can use Stirling's large-$n$ approximation, that is
$$
\ln(n!) \approx n\ln(n) -n + \frac{1}{2}\ln(n)+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)
$$
to show that, after some algebra,
\begin{aligned}
\ln(a_n) &= \ln\bigl((2n-1)!\bigr) - \ln(n!) - \ln\bigl((n-1)!\bigr) - (n-1)\ln(2) \\
&\approx n\ln(2) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(n)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\pi)
\end{aligned}
or, equivalently,
$$
a_n \approx \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}}.
$$

Comment: Like I mentioned in the original post, i saw the graph and did see how it grew to infinity. My question is not how fast it grows, but specifically what happens when n is infinity

Comment: hmm, actually i guess that wouldnt be the LIMIT as it approaches n. i see the mistake i have made.